# Electron with imports (polymer)

Tags: polymer, electron

I'm trying to create an electron app with polymer. I tried to import a custom element using

```
<link rel="import" href="src/lux-app.html">
```

but it dosen't work. Console says:

```
GET file:///D:/src/lux-app.html net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

It does not use the correct path. I researched and found that imports only work when they are on a server (e.g. localhost). Is there a way to run localhost in electron or something like that?

Thank you

**Edit:**
Here is the file structure

```
lux-app
   |── bower_components
   |── images
   |── lib
       └── artnet.js
   |── lux-app.html
   |── .gitignore
   |── bower.json
   |── ...
node_modules
   └── node stuff
main.js
index.html
polymer.json
package.json
README.json
renderer.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imports work without "localhost", as i see in ["Electron Api demos"](https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos). In the ***index.html*** file,  there are some imports like these:

```
<link rel="import" href="sections/about.html">
<link rel="import" href="sections/windows/windows.html">
<link rel="import" href="sections/windows/crash-hang.html">
<link rel="import" href="sections/menus/menus.html">
```

So i think your problem is that the **path** variable in the main renderer (main.js) don't work properly, or if you haven't declared that variable, you need to with `const path = require('path')` and use the path as in the *main.js* file in the Electron Api demos.

(I'm not an expert with electron, but i think I can get you oriented to the solution looking inside the files in electron api repo)

Comment: It worked, but I had to remove <base href="/"> and <script>window.Polymer = {rootPath: '/'};</script>. Thanks a lot!